# LatLngBounds from polygon in a kml file?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gis, kml, polygon

I am new to google maps and the API, trying to have the map pan to an area on a click. I'm not having a great time finding what I need in the API reference and not at all sure how to go about this so I don't have much but here is what I have so far.

I want to make it so clicking any region will pan over to and zoom in to display most of that region, which I believe is what [panToBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) is meant to do.

Most of the functionality will be coming from clicking on text names and having the map load showing the right location, rather than clicking around on the map itself

```
function initialize_neighbourhoodmap(neighbourhood_name) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.949442,-81.228125);

    var zoom = 11;
    var neighbourhood_center = get_neighbourhood_center();

    var myOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("neighbourhood_map"),
        myOptions);

    var neighbourhoods = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&ie=UTF8&hl=en&oe=UTF8&vps=3&msa=0&output=kml&msid=217366496682144933685.0004bf3be50d3cd7ad1c2', {suppressInfoWindows: true, preserveViewport:true});
    neighbourhoods.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(neighbourhoods, 'click', function(KmlFeatureData) {
        var neighbourhood_name = KmlFeatureData.featureData.name;
    load_neighbourhood(neighbourhood_name, neighbourhoods);
    window.location = "#neighbourhood-neighbourhood "+neighbourhood_name;
    });

    if(typeof neighbourhood_name !== 'undefined'){
        load_neighbourhood(neighbourhood_name, neighbourhood_center);
    }
}

function load_neighbourhood (neighbourhood_name, neighbourhoods) {
    var neighbourhoodbounds = nonexistentgetboundsfunction(neighbourhood_name);
    map.panToBounds(neighbourhood_center[neighbourhood_name][0]);
    $('#neighbourhood h2').html('neighbourhood '+neighbourhood_name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Surely you want other functionality? The UI becomes awkward in my opinion. Well, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/g343k/3/

I have run into a strange "bug", or some may call "feature", which is associated to the KML polygon. When a region is clicked the map pans to the center of the region; however, when the outside planning_district area is clicked, the map pans to the center of the box, not to where the click is (Sean Mickey tested in FireFox 12 and it pans to the click). I can't figure out a way around this other than subdividing the planning district into dozens of smaller boxes :( Right now I have written the code to ignore clicks to the planning district.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(neighbourhoods, 'click', function(KmlFeatureData) {
        var neighbourhood_name = KmlFeatureData.featureData.name;
    load_neighbourhood(neighbourhood_name, neighbourhoods);
    window.location = "#neighbourhood-neighbourhood "+neighbourhood_name;
    // ADDED
    // Consider what to do when this outer area is clicked
    if(KmlFeatureData.featureData.name!="planning_districts_2008") {
      map.panTo(KmlFeatureData.latLng);
    }

    });

    // LEFT OUT
    //if(typeof neighbourhood_name !== 'undefined'){
    //    load_neighbourhood(neighbourhood_name, neighbourhood_center);
    //}

    // ADDED
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      map.panTo(event.latLng);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think I see what you are describing; it seems to be working as it was described in the question.

Comment: @SeanMickey  The part I don't have working is clicking just outside of the large outlined shape (example: Lockwood Park on bottom right). The map won't center to the clicked point, instead, to the center of the outlined region.

Comment: That isn't what I'm seeing. The point I click is panned to the center, whether I am in the kml section our outside. I can see the cursor switch to pointer over the kml area and it remains the default outside of that area. Regardless of the cursor, kml or not, whatever point I click is panned to the center. I'm running in FF 12.

Comment: If it doesn't work the same in all modern browsers, I call it a bug :( I have IE, Chrome, and Opera all center to the middle of the marked area. I have a hack, which is to do nothing if this "invisible" region is clicked.

Comment: Just to clarify, it looks like it is working fine in Firefox. It behaves as it should and just as described, so I'm not seeing a bug or any problems.

Comment: I was looking at panToBounds because I was assuming that would include zoom as well.. I want the area in question to fill most of the viewport, not just center the map on where was clicked

Comment: There's `fitBounds` which is not perfect but it zooms in and out to the given bounds. I just don't see a way of getting a bounding box of a neighbourhood out of the click event. I can only think of a time-consuming hack (saving the bounds in the KML then retrieving it with the click)

Comment: Yeah hrm. There's a different kml file already done where the centre/zoom level of each region was stored in an array (that's what `neighbourhood_center[neighbourhood_name][0]` ) was about.. but that seemed too tedious to figure out manually for every neighbourhood. I was thinking there must be some reasonable way to calculate the latlngbounds from a polygon in a kml file